# Limiting user input

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I have written the following code and to a large extent it does what I want it to do.  The issue is that when the user can enter something like "111" and the output is "You entered the number 1."  I want to limit the user's input to 1 character.  Any suggestions?  I'm sure the solution is quite simple, but I can't figure it out.  Also, the code must remain in the form of a switch statement.  Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char i;

    cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 9." << endl;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> i;

    switch (i)
        {
        case '1':
            cout << "You entered the number one." << endl;
            break;

        case '2':
            cout << "You entered the number two." << endl;
            break;

        case '3':
            cout << "You entered the number three." << endl;
            break;

        case '4':
            cout << "You entered the number four." << endl;
            break;

        case '5':
            cout << "You entered the number five." << endl;
            break;

        case '6':
            cout << "You entered the number six." << endl;
            break;

        case '7':
            cout << "You entered the number seven." << endl;
            break;

        case '8':
            cout << "You entered the number eight." << endl;
            break;

        case '9':
            cout << "You entered the number nine." << endl;
            break;

        default:
            cout << "You did not enter a valid number." << endl;
            break;
        }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have limited the input to one character. There's no way to prevent them from typing any more in standard C++.

Comment: What is your form of input?

Comment: In the console the user can type any myriad of numbers or characters.  E.g. if the user types a, then the output will be "You did not enter a valid number."  Another example is if the user types 19, then the program will output "You entered the number 1." where the number 1 is the first character the user typed.  The issue is that I want the program to reject any number that is not somewhere between 1 to 9.  Am I making sense?

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. If you want the program to validate more than one character, why you limit it to only accept a single character? Just read the whole input stream from user and validate the string.

Comment: @chris really, there's no way (barring cyborg invasion or hardware failure) to keep them from typing more in any language or platform. I think this stems from a fundamental lack of understanding of how a keyboard buffer works. (OP, not you.)

Comment: @DavidLively, I might be on a different page, but take Windows. You could at least make it appear like no more can be typed by disabling line input with [`SetConsoleMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686033(v=vs.85).aspx) and then enabling/disabling the echo with the same function when needed. Of course this is not in any way portable (though Linux should have something similar AFAIK). Anyway, it actually seems I misunderstood the question and that groups of numbers should be processed and dealt with.

Comment: Thank you all for your input.  We went beyond the scope of what I was trying to accomplish.  Effectively I wanted the program to only accept and give an output for the user entering 1 through 9.  I accomplished this, with some help of course, by changing the char i to an int n.  Now, if the user enters anything besides 1 through 9, then the output of the program is "You did not enter a valid number."  which is what I wanted.  Thank you all again.

Comment: @chris okay, that makes sense. My comment was really saying "Well, they're going to keep hitting keys. Perhaps some sort of negative bio-feedback device (ie, you get shocked or whacked in the head) would work." I blame lack of coffee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one way that would be easy: Just switch the `char c` to `int n` and replace the `case '1'` with `case 1` etc. Try this until the user enters a valid number and then enter "a" (i.e. something that is not a number). As often, the easy way is also the wrong way. ;)

Now, what you could do instead is to use this bit of code:

```
std::string line;
while (getline(std::cin, line))
{
    if (line == "1") {
        std::cout << "You entered the number one." << std::endl;
    } else if (line == "2") {
        // ....
    } else {
        std::cout << "You didn't enter a valid number" << std::endl;
    }         
}
```

The difference here is that since the input is line-base without further interpretation, the streamstate isn't modified when the input can't be interpreted as a number. This is typically more robust when interacting with the user. If later you want to have the number numerically, check out stringstreams or lexical_cast for conversion.

Comment: I re-wrote the code and your first suggestion worked.  Why would using an int vice a char work better?  I'm trying to understand, not just get the right answer.  Thank you.

Comment: @user3727648 It works because in your switch statement you're comparing `i` to characters, not integers. Did you change `case '1':`, `case '2':` etc. to `case 1:`, `case 2:`, etc.? If you didn't that would be the reason.

Comment: Yes, I changed the char i to int n and all the case '1': to case 1: etc.  The code works just the way I want it to now.  Thank you.

Comment: @user3727648 If this answer helped you would you mind clicking the checkmark next to his answer? It lets the community know that you've recieved a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about that feature.  I appreciate the information.

Comment: I appreciate that you tried the first one instead of just using the second one. However, please try to enter something that is not a number and then try read *any* other input. You will find that you can't, which is because the streamstate goes to 'fail', which you have to clear explicitly. The second version doesn't suffer this problem, as it reads a line without interpreting it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use getchar(char) from the c standard io library.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    ...
    char i;
    int j;

    cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 9." << endl;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    getchar(j);
    i=(char)j;
    switch(i){
    ...
```

Comment: The OP is already reading a single character. What advantage does this offer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use getch() to get a single char from the screen, you can check if it's a number and otherwise ask again for a valid input.

Comment: This is very unportable and oldschool (say around DOS times)... :-)